# Save a Matrix in Matlab to a bin file and read it in c++

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, binaryfiles, eigen

I saved an integer 10x10 matrix `I` in Matlab into a binary file using fwrite:

```
fid = fopen('True.bin' , 'w');
fwrite(fid , I , 'int');
fclose(fid)
```

Now when I try to open it in C++ using fstream library, it returns an error. The C++ code is as follows:

```
int IMG_SIZE = 10;
char * buffer;
long size = IMG_SIZE * IMG_SIZE;
ifstream file ("True.bin", ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
buffer = new char [size];
file.read (buffer, size);
file.close();
```

Any idea how to load the file into an array, or Eigen matrix of type `MatrixXi` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write values using the `'int'` value for the `precision` argument to `fwrite`, it writes them as 4-byte integers, so your 10x10 matrix will take up 10x10x4 = 400 bytes.  But you are only allocating a buffer that is 10x10 = 100 bytes long.

Comment: Other than that, it's a bit hard to know what the problem is without telling us what error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I changed the `size` to `10*10*4` and still returns error. Variable `I` is a matrix of 10x10 integer values that I have calculated in Matlab. I want to load it to the C++ program and do some matrix calculations on it. But apparently c++ file.read only reads in the char variables, not integers